# Is there a way to disable the default pch file in CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods

CocoaPods always generates a default pch file containing

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#ifndef FOUNDATION_EXPORT
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

for building the library. I found that the [prefix_header_file](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#prefix_header_file) option appends the file to the default.

I'd like to build the library inside and outside of CocoaPods and avoid pch files.

Is there a way to disable the pch file completely in CocoaPods?

Comment: See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, I discovered that CocoaPods did not have an option to disable prefix_header generation.

I sent a [Pull Request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7044) to make it possible and it recently merged.

After the next CocoaPods 1.4.0 beta, it will be possible to disable prefix_header generation by setting the podspec attribute `prefix_header_file` to false:

> spec.prefix_header_file = false